# Request headers in APITestCase

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I have a test (`APITestCase`), and I need to specify custom headers:

```
class ListAppsAPITest(APITestCase):
    def test_list_apps_versions(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('api:applications:list'), None, **{'Device-Id': 'deadbeef'})
```

I've tried different combinations of arguments, but it did not work.

How to specify custom headers in tests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because Django have they own way to define the header, you can take a look at [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) to see why and how to achieve that.

> With the exception of CONTENT_LENGTH and CONTENT_TYPE, as given above, any HTTP headers in the request are converted to META keys by converting all characters to uppercase, replacing any hyphens with underscores and adding an HTTP_ prefix to the name. So, for example, a header called X-Bender would be mapped to the META key HTTP_X_BENDER.

In your case, like so:

```py
class ListAppsAPITest(APITestCase):
    def test_list_apps_versions(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('api:applications:list'), None, **{'HTTP_DEVICE_ID': 'deadbeef'})
```

Hope that helps!